# Writing script in win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application") to update link to excel and to break the links in the same function

Tags: python, powerpoint, win32com, excel-interop, powerpoint-interop

I was tasked with building a multi-step program that took a large Excel file's tabs, which were updated based on a unique cell value, and then import some of those tabs into a unique Powerpoint, which is then saved into a folder and that folder than grows larger as the program loops through multiple value, which continues to update the Excel file.

I originally used vba, but found that vba in Excel does not allow me to update links that sit in Powerpoint, only Excel links would work.

In a nutshell the code below takes a value from my looper file, inputs it into Excel, which then updates the Powerpoint slides that are linked to those tabs. My solution works, but when I open the files, I must click don't update links or else it reverts to whatever tabs are showing on the Excel file.

**My problem is that I don't know how to break the links to Excel file in the Powerpoint before it gets saved. I have tried several functions and they all don't seem to work.**

Below is my code:

```
def fun_times():
    # Set the path to the existing PowerPoint file
    existing_ppt_path = r"C:/Users/dtalbot2/Desktop/x.pptm"
    
    # Create PowerPoint application
    ppt_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppt_app.Visible = True  # Uncomment this line if you want PowerPoint to be visible
    
    # Open the existing PowerPoint presentation
    ppt_pres = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(existing_ppt_path)
    
    # Get the Excel application
    excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    
    # Set paths and filenames
    looper_path = r"C:/Users/dtalbot2/Desktop/Looper1.xlsx"
    b_p_path = r"C:/Users/dtalbot2/Desktop/z.xlsm"


    for i in range(1, 181):
        # Activate Looper workbook
        base_wb = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(looper_path)
        base_wb.Activate()
        
        # Set value in Looper worksheet
        base_wb.Worksheets("Looper").Range("E1").Value = i
        retailer_name = base_wb.Worksheets("Looper").Range("F1").Value
        retailer_code = base_wb.Worksheets("Looper").Range("G1").Value
        this_file_name = r"C:\Users\dtalbot2\Documents\BP\\" + str(retailer_name)
        
        # Activate B_P workbook
        target_wb = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(b_p_path)
        target_wb.Activate()
        
        # Set value in B_P worksheet
        target_wb.Worksheets("BP Cover").Range("AF8").Value = retailer_code
        
        ppt_pres.UpdateLinks()

        
        # Save the PowerPoint presentation with the specified filename
        ppt_pres.SaveAs(this_file_name + ".pptx")  # You can change the extension if needed
        
        # Close workbooks
        base_wb.Close(False)
        target_wb.Close(False)

    # Close PowerPoint presentation
    ppt_pres.Close()
    
    # Close PowerPoint application
    ppt_app.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun_times()
```

I tried defining a break link function above the fun_times() functions and then including it in the fun times function and that didn't work. Instead the program basically gets stuck at break link function. It doesn't work.

Comment: Alright, I solved it with a different solution. It's not great but it works. I used powerpoint VBA to located my saved powerpoints and it worked.